# Separating a list into sublists in python

Tags: python, list, append, sublist

I am trying to create a tool that takes in a str of integers and a number of items per sublist, then produces a list object that has all the sublists nested inside of it.  For example:

> inputs:
>
> ```
> str of ints: '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
> length of subsets:3
> ```
>
> output:
>       [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

I am stuck as to how to create the sublists given the user input of sublist length.  Here is my code so far....

```
b= []

def makeList():
    c = input("Drop your number list in here")
    d = input("How many per sublist?")
    newList = c.split()
    for i in newList:
        b.append(int(i))
```

this only leaves me with a list of integers.  Is there a method that will do this easily? Or do I need to fight with a subloop iterating over the list, appending and popping as I go?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate chunk size:

```
chunk_sz = int(len(lst) / chunks) + 1
```

then chunk:

```
[lst[i:i+chunk_sz] for i in range(0, len(lst), chunk_sz)]
```

Comment: Lol who voted this down this is pretty correct...

Comment: I made a mistake at first, but corrected it after the dv

Answer (score 0):

```
l = list(range(1, 10))
def split(l, size):
    return [l[i : i + size] for i in range(0, len(l), size)]
print(split(l, 3))
```

This outputs:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```